# qt gui transported from windows to linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, layout

i wrote an application in qt creator and designed it on windows.

when i'm running the application on Linux the size of the controls is too small.
all the controls are in layout.

which property should i change?

Comment: I would avoid hacking around the platform-specific style. Is it really broken or just different from what you expect? Screenshots would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`minimumSize` should do the trick. It ensures your controls have at least this size, but they can still grow if needed (for example because of bigger fonts depending on the platform, and, for instance dpi settings). But this setting would also affect your windows version.

Another way would be to override the `pixelMetric()` method of your linux QStyle to return bigger values.

The `QStyle::PM_DefaultFrameWidth` PixelMetric enum could be the starting point in your case, I think.